# How do I change the value of a textarea when using a reuseable component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to change the text within a specific component's textarea when requirements are met from entering text into a different components textarea. I've tried to create a simple example to show the issue. my main issue is targeting the correct component and editing its text that shows up dynamically.

Parent Component

```
<template>
    <reuseableComponent 
        input-type="textarea" v-model="Example1">
    </reuseableComponent>
    <reuseableComponent 
        input-type="textarea" v-model="Example2">
    </reuseableComponent>
<template>
```

Reuseable Component

```
<textarea
    v-model='taValue' @input='$emit("input", taValue)'>
</textarea>

exampleMethod() {
    if(value) {
        //change text in Example2 textarea instance.
    }
}
```

Comment: you will need to take a further look into vuejs binding etc and also their events. Also adding more code for the component as its a little lacking in actual vuejs code. So its not helping to figure out what you have done and whats need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got it right, you are trying to change the second component's value if the first component's value matches a certain criteria. So, If that's the case, I have produced a working fiddle that you may find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mrzerehpoosh/Lnkrjqy6/), which by typing *Foo* in first reusable textarea you will get *Bar* in second textarea.

```js
window.Event = new Vue();

Vue.component('my-textarea', {
 template: `
   <textarea :value="value" 
        @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" 
                 :placeholder="placeholder"
        ref="input"
    >
    </textarea>`,
  props: {
   value: { default: '' },
        placeholder: { default: '' }
  },
  methods: {
   updateValue(value) {
      // adding v-model support to this reusable component
      this.$refs.input.value = value;
      this.$emit('input', value);
          
       // Firing an event via Event bus to notify sibling reusable component
       Event.$emit('valueChanged', this._uid, value);
     }
  },
  
  mounted() {
        // Listening for 'valueChanged' event
   Event.$on('valueChanged', (id, value) => {
     if (id != this._uid) {
           if (value === 'Foo') {
         this.$refs.input.value = 'Bar';
        }
      }
    }); 
  }
  
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
      return {
     text1: '',
        text2: ''
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <my-textarea v-model="text1" placeholder="Type Foo here"></my-textarea>
  <my-textarea v-model="text2"></my-textarea>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrzerehpoosh/Lnkrjqy6/

Comment: this looks like the functionality i'm looking for, but I have the data tied to a state with Vuex, I'll see if I can get this to work with my setup. Thanks!